# php curl post file and data with same key at same time

Tags: php, curl

I have to post a file and some another data with php cURL.

The problem is that if I send a file through cURL the post data has to be an array (CURLFILE). But I have other post fields which contains same array keys (and it is not possible in a php array):

```
$PostData = array (
  "document[$docIndex].Id" => "$id",
  "document[$docIndex].Attachement"=> new CURLFILE($file_to_upload,'application/pdf','filename'),
  "document[$docIndex].subdata.index" => "$index1",
  "document[$docIndex].subdata.index" => "$index2"
  );
```

I can post the data with same keys through string, but I can't send files as string, and on the other hand I can't post data with same keys as array.

Anybody has a solution for it?
(I have to use php 7.x so I can't try the CURLStringFile)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"(I have to use php 7.x so I can't try the CURLStringFile)"_ - that would not help you anyway - they both _return_ the same thing (more or less), only the way they get populated with the file data in the first place is different.